# Can we show selected value from the list got back from server in bootstrap typehead when loaded on UI

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap

Once i recieve the data back from server , i create my collections as

```
var actionTypeCollection = new Backbone.Collection(responseMsg);
```

and then create the multisuggest box, now once the data is saved backed to the server from this page, my question is that when i reload the page back is it possible to load this box with data saved in my DB

```
  $('input[name="actiontype"]').multisuggest({
        sources: [
            {
                type: 'backbone.collection',
                data: actionTypeCollection,
                filter: actionComboCollectionFilter,
                listFormatter: actionComboCollectionListFormatter,
                inputFormatter: actionComboCollectionInputFormatter,
                valueAttribute: actionComboCollectionValueAttribute
            }
        ],              
        loadingIconClass: 'msuggest-loading',
        noResultsText: 'No matching cheeses.',
        enableDropdownMode: true,
        delay: 300,
        minLength: 2
    });
```

Comment: after you save the object simply recall the service to get the data, or on success on save take the selected object and update your page based on that.  The second assumes that since the service succeeded that this infers that the database updated.

Comment: Hey Thanks for replying, Once the model is loaded i need to show the item as selected in the dropdown, i tried the render method or the updater, i am looking for something like setter as we have for jquery $("#id").val('something');

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x3UyB/2/ shows a working example of this

Comment: @abc123 thanks for the reply, The fiddle is for any normal select, what i want is autocomplete to be pre populated with one value, for eg: if you look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hyxMh/48/ , what i need is the autocomplete box to be prepopulated with one of the values, when the page loads

Comment: from what I can tell your code doesn't work as is...However, after you populate the list simply set the dropdown value to what you want. otherwise you could call the ajax request repeatedly to get the names list but that's not even a good idea with caching i'd use clientside caching here.